# Compare two strings in sharepoint workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

Is it possible to compare two Strings in a 2013 sharepoint workflow?

e.g. in an If statement, If "Apple" less than "Banana" ...

Expected result is true: "Apple" is less than "Banana" (because "Apple" is alphabetically before  "Banana")

Comment: what result do you expect? "Apple" less then "Banana"????

Comment: Updated question to include expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a String variable named `alphabet` and set the value `aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIgGkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ` there. Please doublecheck if it fits English Alphabet because I learned it 27 years ago.
2. Copy the first character from both of the Strings `Apple` and `Banana` into substrings.
3. Use the action *find Substring in String* against both Substrings. Save the result to Integer variables `String1index` and `String2index`.
4. Add usual condition `If String1index is less than or equal to String2index`

[image]

[image]